# How do I get selected spinner value in intent?

Tags: android

How do I get spinner selected position in intent and pass it as parameter to another Activity?

```
 spinner  sp;
if (position==1) {
 do this
} if (position==2) {
 do this
}

Intent i = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), AgAppMenu.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("mno", mobile.getText().toString());
bundle.putString("pinno", pin.getText().toString());
bundle.putLong("CODE",sp.getSelectedItemPosition());
```

Comment: Accept Answer.by ticking right mark to it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you want to do?

```
sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> av, View v,
                    int pos, long id) {
                //do something with the pos var
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}                       
        });
```

Comment: this only show position  i want to pas as a parameter spiner position value

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly. Now all you are missing is

```
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

EDIT:

To get the value, use

```
(YourType) sp.getSelectedItem();
```

where `YourType` is the type of the value you wish to get. If it's `Long`, cast it to `Long`.

Comment: no no i didnot paste it  i want to get spinner selected value at this line 

 bundle.putLong("CODE",sp.getSelectedItemPosition());

Comment: this line  sp.getSelectedItemPosition()

did not get spinner selected value

Comment: If you're trying to get the value of the selected item, please edit your question to state that you're looking for the VALUE, not the POSITION.

Answer (score 0):

define a class variable (here String selectedMonth) and  assign it value in the following method and then use this variable in intent

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView month, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {

```
    selectedMonth=  month.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();

        }
```

Comment: i do not want to give hard code value i want to give dynamic value in intent what ever value user select at spiner its go as a parameter to another activity

Answer (score 0):

```
String item;
sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
item = (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
}
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
});

Intent i = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), AgAppMenu.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); bundle.putString("CODE",item);
```

Comment: this code will show selected value if i add 4 positions in spinner?